# Como definir tipos pré definidos no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

No site que estou desenvolvendo terei, por exemplo, um formulário de cadastro onde o usuário deve definir seu sexo em uma *combobox* (masculino ou feminino). A tabela usuários na base de dados terá todos os campos do usuário como `string`, `date`, `float`. Como faço para definir o `sexo`?

Para que na *combobox* de cadastro eu já carregue a opção masculino e feminino e na base cadastre como M ou F, já tendo essas duas opções lá cadastradas. Assim teria que aparecer ao usuário 'Masculino' ou 'Feminino' sendo que na tabela do banco de dados eu tenho isso como campo sexo tendo como opção desse campo somente M ou F.

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, bastaria você fazer este "de-para" entre Masculino ser `M` e Feminino ser `F` na aplicação antes de obter/salvar esta informação no banco de dados. É esta a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O MySQL não tem nenhum recurso para criar um [domínio de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_domain) como existe em outros bancos de dados.

A solução normalmente adotada é criar uma [enumeração](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html), embora muitos dizem que o ideal é não usar este tipo de dado. Ou criar uma tabela auxiliar com os dados que precisa e fazer um relacionamento.

A segunda forma tem diversas maneiras de fazer de acordo com sua necessidade. Mas todas envolverão algum trabalho manual. Não tem jeito.

Neste caso o mais comum para pegar os valores possíveis é só olhar para a tabela auxiliar, no caso seria a tabela de sexo ou gênero como seria uma nomenclatura mais correta. Quando fizer alguma consulta na tabela de usuário terá que fazer um `JOIN` para que a coluna de sexo pegue a descrição na tabela auxiliar ao invés do código/id do sexo escolhido.

Uma outra forma é não se preocupar com isso no banco de dados, cadastrar as letras referentes ao gênero na coluna e tratar as descrições só na aplicação. Em geral este informação não costuma mudar.

Como curiosidade há um [padrão para representar dados de gênero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218) e ao contrário do que pensam as pessoas, não deve se usar "M" ou "F".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para algumas aplicações esta tabela pode ser muito restrita.