# Varchar ou int para campos "tipo"

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

Tenho uma coluna **tipo** com 6 opções para salvar no banco, é melhor salvar a `string` como `varchar` ou como int e tratar isso no *front*? Por exemplo, quando for 1 no banco, exibir certa *string* na tela e assim por diante.

Sei que `int` teria mais desempenho, mas gostaria de saber se tem muita dor de cabeça ou risco de inconsistência. Pensei em salvar como `varchar` mesmo para não ter que ficar tratando isso.

Comment: Você pode usar o type como ENUM ou SET

Comment: Normalmente uso `tinyint()`.

Comment: @Coringa legal, não conhecia esses tipos, vou dar uma olhada, valeu. Daniel, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não dá para afirmar sem entender o que deseja de fato, sem conhecer todo o contexto.

Eu diria que é melhor usar um `int` ou até um tipo numérico inteiro de menor tamanho já que são apenas 6 opções.

Não acho que seja desejável ter o espaço do texto ocupado na tabela. Mas o problema pior é se tiver que mudar o nome de um desses tipos. Pode ser que seja útil fazer isso.

Isso é considerado uma enumeração e alguns bancos de dados possuem forma própria de lidar com isso. Mas é comum ser mais vantajoso ter uma tabela normalizada com as descrições. Claro que a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) gera algum custo extra, mas se tudo ocorrer bem estará no cache e o custo será bem pequeno. Mas pode ser exagero fazer isso.

O problema de tratar na aplicação é que se precisar mudar um nome, ou adicionar um tipo novo, terá que dar o devido tratamento nela, nem todo mundo sabe fazer isso da forma correta. Mas está longe de estar errado. Pode ser que seja a solução mais simples.

Riscos sempre existem em cada uma dessas soluções. Se fizer errado qualquer uma pode não funcionar direito. Mas nenhum tem riscos óbvios mesmo fazendo certo.

Dê uma olhada:

- [Qual atributo usar para campos da base de dados que trabalhem com números de 0 à 5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53684/101)
- [Armazenar valores representantes do 'sexo' de um usuário em bancos de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57429/101)
- [Qual a vantagem em usar o tipo ENUM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101)
- [Como definir tipos pré definidos no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81012/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, ficou bem claro agora. Então usarei uma tabela com a descrição, mas como vou usar isso mais vezes, muitas tabelas com descrições prejudicará o desempenho? Usar somente int e tratar na aplicação é considerado má prática? Aproveitando, no outro post você disse para não usar boolean mesmo se forem 2 valores apenas, em qual cenário deve-se usar boolean no bd? Obrigado.

Comment: Não, ter muitas tabelas não prejudica. Há quem goste que criar uma só com todas descrição, aí teria 3 colunas, uma dizendo sobre que tipo de descrição é, outra que identifica a descrição e a terceira que é a descrição em si. Eu já fiz isso no passado porque havia restrições diversas, hoje não vejo necessidade de fazer isso mais. Não tem nada de ruim em fazer na aplicação, só tem que fazer certo, mas isso vale para qualquer solução. Essa de não usar booleano depende do caso. Só use se realmente os valores sem SIM e NÃO e nunca vá mudar, se for outra coisa, não use, caso do sexo.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado, @bigown, ajudou muito!