# O que usar para armazenar status em banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, modelagem, armazenamento

Estou criando um banco de dados em MySQL e nele vai haver uma tabela para fazer controle de ponto: quando o funcionário iniciou o expediente, quando encerrou, quando parou para almoçar e etc.

Estive fazendo um protótipo de tabela:

```
+------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| employee_name    | datetime_registered | status | register | observation |
+------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| Fulando da Silva | 2020-10-28 14:49:00 | 0      |        1 | NULL        |
+------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Sendo que `status` é um código que vai traduzir para: início de expediente, término de expediente e etc. E o backend teria uma regra de negócio para fazer essa tradução do código para o valor. Pensei dessa forma para economia de memória, uma vez que armazenar uma string de tipo 'Início de expediente' ocupa mais memória a longo prazo que apenas '0', '1' ou '2'.

Porém não acho que essa seja a melhor prática para isso. Pesquisei sobre e não achei nada diretamente relacionado a isso.

Explicando o restante da tabela: o campo `employee_name` guarda o nome do funcionário, o campo `datetime_registered` guarda o horário que o status de expediente foi atualizado, `register` é o id de cada registro, sendo a chave primária da tabela, e `observation` é um campo de texto que armazena alguma ocasional justificativa, caso o funcionário encerre o expediente mais cedo e precise justificar de forma sucinta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece óbvio que o tipo [`tinyint`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) é o mais adequado para guardar os códigos de estado e depois na aplicação faz a descrição em cima de cada código. Mas qualquer inteiro pode ser útil se o espaço não for absurdamente restrito. Já falei sobre isso em [Varchar ou int para campos "tipo"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159284/101).

Algumas pessoas podem pensar em um `enum` mas não vejo vantagem. Tem *link* na resposta *linkada* que fala das desvantagens disso.

E claro que pode ter uma tabela auxiliar com a descrição dos estados, que pode trazer alguma vantagem, mas acho que traz desvantagens demais para adotar. Toda consulta teria que fazer uma busca secundária o que deixaria lento. Teria que usar uma chave estrangeira. Em alguns cenários pode não ser um problema, mas acho que complica a escrita, deixa lento para ter uma facilidade muito pequena na leitura que a desvantagem acaba anulando.

Não consigo imaginar um motivo forte pra usar *string* nesse caso porque é um código identificador, não é algo descritivo, mas também não é um grande problema, mesmo consumindo um espaço um pouco maior, só acho mais fácil o número.

Não sei o problema todo, mas **pode** ser que a modelagem esteja ruim e deveria fazer outra solução que talvez nem envolva essa coluna. Pode ser o ideal assim mesmo, só estou abrindo a porta para pensar sobre.

Answer (score 0):

> Pensei dessa forma para economia de memória, uma vez que armazenar uma
> string de tipo 'Início de expediente' ocupa mais memória a longo prazo
> que apenas '0', '1' ou '2'.
>
> Porém não acho que essa seja a melhor prática para isso. Pesquisei
> sobre e não achei nada diretamente relacionado a isso.

Primeiro, o status pode ser descrito no banco de dados normalmente, o problema aqui é que isso está desnormalizando a tua tabela.
Se o objetivo da tabela é armazenar os dados de ponto, e o status não faz parte da chave, segundo a normalização deveria estar numa entidade diferente, por exemplo "RegisterStatus".
Essa tabela sim pode ter o id e a descrição do status, deve haver um único registro por descrição, sendo o espaço consumido irrelevante baseado no que colocou como exemplo, e na tabela que colocou no exemplo, apenas o id, que seria a chave estrangeira. O seja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, uma tabela/entidade para o status, que resolve o problema da descrição, e uma *foreign key* na outra tabela, resolvendo o problema do tipo do campo e também da correta normalização do modelo.